# Show $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac {5} {n}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, proof-writing

*My proof:*

> Let $\varepsilon >0$. By the Archimedean property, there is a $N$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that $\dfrac {1} {N}\varepsilon < 1$. Hence, we obtain $N < \dfrac {1} {\varepsilon }$. Thus, for all $n\geq N$
>   $$\left| \dfrac {5} {n}-0\right|=\dfrac {5} {n}=\dfrac {1} {n(\dfrac {1} {5})}<\dfrac {1} {n}<\dfrac {1} {N}<\varepsilon. $$
>   We are done.

**Can you check my proof and mathematical writing (proof-writing)?**

Comment: It is not true that $\frac{5}{n} < \frac{1}{n}$. Perhaps just proceed from $|\frac{5}{n}| = \frac{5}{n} \leq \frac{5}{N}$ since $n\geq N$ and choose $N$ such that $\frac{5}{\epsilon} < N$.

Comment: @Weaam Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

As Weaam wrote,
$\dfrac {1} {n(\dfrac {1} {5})}
<\dfrac {1} {n}
$
is false.

You want $n$ to be large enough
so that
$\dfrac {5} {n}
<\varepsilon
$.
This is equivalent to
$\dfrac {5} {\varepsilon}
<n
$,
and *this* is
the lower bound on $n$
that is needed.

Comment: Then, we should say 'by the Archimedean property there is a $N$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that $N\varepsilon > 5$. Hence, we obtain $\dfrac {5} {N } < \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ε>0$ By the Archimedean property,$\quad\exists n_0\in\mathbb{N},\quad n_0\varepsilon>5\iff n_0>\dfrac{5}{\varepsilon}$

We can choose $n_0=\left\lfloor\dfrac{5}{\varepsilon}\right\rfloor+1$